# Suppress NU1202, keep as warning when trusted package

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have problem with nuget restore on vsts `error NU1202: Package *** is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package *** supports: net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8)`

It started happing after i upgraded one project with test to `.net6` before this was only warning.

But when i build it localy it works without problem
When i do `msbuild -restore` or `dotnet -restore` locally it works and this error is only warning

How can I suppress NU1202 on vsts ?

Locally I got this warning instead error

```
 warning NU1701: Package '****' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6
.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Comment: you can't. If a package can't be used in net6, it can't be used. How do you intent to build a project that depends on a package, when that package simply isn't there? I wonder why you got the warning at all **before** upgrading.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain check my updated question, u see , when I compile this locally i got only this warning